# iOS Tablet app: modal or sticky comments to questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, ios-app, ipad

Having just tapped out a nice long comment to a question using the stackoverflow  app on my iPad, and then accidentally clicked outside the comment field, I have one request:

Please, please make the comment box modal or sticky so that it retains the focus and doesn't dump the comment should your finger wander out of the box. Please?

Comment: Can you tell me where you tapped that made the box disappear completely?

Comment: I was on the main stackexchange "page" or screen on the app (the one you get when you switch between whatever sites you subscribe too). Question list on the left, question on the right. I was adding a comment to the question on the right. I think I clicked on the question list.

Comment: I plan to work on a solution to this issue after the next release of the app. Probably an alert to warn users that they are leaving a question with a comment draft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a problem that required careful consideration. I didn't want to make the comment too modal, otherwise the user might lose the context of what they are commenting on. On the other hand, we didn't want users to lose their draft if they accidentally tap on another question in the list or on another item in the menu.

So now, when commenting on iPad, **the question list and menu are temporarily disabled. To restore them, a user has to finish submitting the comment, or discard it**. A hint has been added to the comment field that shows users how to discard the comment. In addition, tapping on the menu button or dragging the navigation bar will enable the menu (in case a user really wants to leave that area).

This change should be visible in **beta version 1.2.0.136** and later.

[image]

Comment: But is the OP here using the iPad app at all? Or does it affect the iOS app for iPhone as well?

Comment: From the comments above, it's implied user was on the iPad app: "Question list on the left, question on the right."

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity in the original comment. I've changed the title and question to make it clear that this was for the tablet version.